# How can I work with Date and Time at Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I've the below model, which have among others, `date` and `time` fields

```
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.LocalTime

@Entity
data class Assignment(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val tid: Int,

   // @PrimaryKey val uid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "task") val task: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "address") val address: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "datePicker") val datePicker: LocalDate?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "timePicker") val timePicker: LocalTime?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "status") val status: String?
)
```

But I got the below error:

> Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can
>   consider adding a type converter for it.

So, I wrote the below convertor:

```
import java.sql.Date
import java.time.LocalDate
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter
import javax.persistence.Converter
import java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault

@Converter(autoApply = true)
class LocalDateAttributeConverter : AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

    override fun convertToDatabaseColumn(locDate: LocalDate?): Date? {
        return if (locDate == null) null else Date.valueOf(locDate.toString())
    }

    override fun convertToEntityAttribute(sqlDate: Date?): LocalDate? {
        val defaultZoneId = systemDefault()
        val instant = sqlDate?.toInstant()
        return instant?.atZone(defaultZoneId)?.toLocalDate()
    }
}
```

But did not know how to use this `convertor` with the database `model`?

**UPDATE**
Based on the received answers, I changed the code to be as below, but still getting the same error:

Converter:

```
import androidx.room.TypeConverter
import java.sql.Date
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault

class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun convertToDatabaseColumn(locDate: LocalDate?): Date? {
        return locDate?.let { Date.valueOf(locDate.toString()) }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun convertToEntityAttribute(sqlDate: Date?): LocalDate? {
        val defaultZoneId = systemDefault()
        val instant = sqlDate?.toInstant()
        return instant?.atZone(defaultZoneId)?.toLocalDate()
    }
}
```

DataBase:

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import androidx.room.TypeConverters
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope

@Database(entities = [Assignment::class], version = 1)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun assignmentDao(): AssignmentDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context,
                        scope: CoroutineScope
        ): AppDatabase {
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance != null) {
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    AppDatabase::class.java,
                    "database-name"
                ).addCallback(AppDatabaseCallback(scope))
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import androidx.room.TypeConverters
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.LocalTime
//import javax.persistence.Convert

@Entity
data class Assignment(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val tid: Int,

   // @PrimaryKey val uid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "task") val task: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "address") val address: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "timePicker") val timePicker: LocalTime?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "status") val status: String?,

    @TypeConverters(Converters::class)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "datePicker") val datePicker: LocalDate?
)
```

Comment: get the `long` value (the time) from your date and save that, then recreate the date from that long value

Comment: @a_local_nobody Kindly see my updated question

Comment: set the database variable for time to long and while assigning a value to it, convert the time value to long by System.currentTimeMillis(). You can even convert them to seconds before inserting

Comment: @Psycho can you give sample code pls.

Comment: I don't know the kotlin syntax for this.. will I show java syntax?

Comment: @Psycho pls do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
long time = new Date().getTime();
long sysTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Both above will return the same value which is long type. So, you can just use one of them. Which can even be converted to Hours, Minutes or Seconds like this (which can be useful when assigning values):

```
int hours = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(System.currentTimeMillis());
int minutes = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(System.currentTimeMillis());
int seconds = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis());

int date = new Date().getDate();
String formatedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
```

here, date will return the value as int (3 for today) and formatedDate will return the value as String (03-08-2019 for today).

So, what you can do in you room database class, declare long type variable for time and int/String (which you prefer) for date. Then, and when assigning values to those variables, use the above techniques.

In Kotlin can be done as:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
       val formatedDate = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(Date())
       val formatedTime = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(Date())
       val DateTime = "$formatedDate  $formatedTime"
       appViewModel.updateLastUpdateById(this, task_id, DateTime)
}
```

And in the Model/Room, as:

```
@Entity
data class Assignment(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "lastUpdate") val lastUpdate: String?
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> But did not know how to use this convertor with the database model?

You are not using the right annotations. `javax.persistence` does not exist in the Android SDK — I would expect your code to fail to compile.

That error message is referring to [Room's `@TypeConverter` and `@TypeConverters` annotations](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data#type-converters).

So, switch your class shown above to use `@TypeConverter`. Then, add `@TypeConverters(LocalDateAttributeConverter::class)` to your `Assignment` entity. Or, if you prefer, add `@TypeConverters(LocalDateAttributeConverter::class)` to your `RoomDatabase` subclass, which will allow you to use `LocalDate` properties in any entity.

Comment: did not understand this `switch your class shown above to use @TypeConverter`

Comment: @HasanAYousef: In your question, you have a `LocalDateAttributeConverter` Kotlin class. This is not using the correct annotations. Change `LocalDateAttributeConverter` to use `@TypeConverter`, following the instructions in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data#type-converters).

Comment: @HasanAYousef: You also need a `LocalTime?` converter. FWIW, see [here](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-andexplore/blob/v0.7/T36-Internet/ToDo/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/todo/repo/TypeTransmogrifier.kt) for a sample Kotlin `@TypeConverter` class and [here](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-andexplore/blob/v0.7/T36-Internet/ToDo/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/todo/repo/ToDoDatabase.kt) for how I applied it to a database.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was using type converter

```
@Database(
entities = [EventCategory::class, Workshop::class, EventDetails::class, UserProfile::class, Message::class],
version = 2,
exportSchema = false
)
@TypeConverters(EventListConverter::class, WorkshopConverter::class, UserProfileConverter::class)
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
@TypeConverters(EventListConverter::class)
abstract fun eventCategoryDao(): EventCategoryDao

@TypeConverters(WorkshopConverter::class)
abstract fun workshopListDao(): WorkshopListDao

abstract fun eventDetailsDao(): EventDetailsDao

@TypeConverters(UserProfileConverter::class)
abstract fun userProfileDao(): UserProfileDao

abstract fun confessionDao(): ConfessionDao
}

val db = Room.databaseBuilder(App.instance, MyDatabase::class.java, "database")
.allowMainThreadQueries()
.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
.build()
```

You can use different type converters for different Dao